# JQuery Weird Animation Looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote two javascripts to write my own modal system because the bootstrap one has so many issues. However when you click it the first time it will work correctly it will fade in, and when you click close it will fade out, but the next time you click show modal and then close modal it will animate 2 times on the fade in and 2 times on the fade out, then I click it a third time and the same thing will happen except it will animate 3 times. and so on. I supposed its how i wrapped my functions but im not quite sure. I'm still noob to javascript. No error is returned in console or debugger.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#helppage').hide();
    });


function displayHelp(){
      $(document).click(function(){
       $( "#helppage" ).fadeIn( "medium", function() {

        });

    });

}


function hideHelp(){
      $(document).click(function(){
       $( "#helppage" ).fadeOut( "medium", function() {

        });
    });

}
```

**SPOKE TO SOON ..**

```
function toggleHelp(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        if ($('#helppage').is(":visible"))  {
             $( "#helppage" ).fadeOut( "medium", function() {

             });
        } else {
             $( "#helppage" ).fadeIn( "medium", function() {

             });
        } 
    });
}
```

**The Real Working Code**

```
**$(function toggleHelp() {
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('#helppage').fadeToggle('medium', function() {
    });
  });
});**
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a condition on whether `#helppage` is displayed or not?

Comment: Thank you , im new to javascript syntax sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize.

Comment: its the `(document).click()` inside your function definition. See my answer below.

Comment: Yeap... Much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding click events to the document each time the user clicks on the document. So each subsequent click and another instance to be triggered when the user clicks. So the firsat time its once, the second time it fires twice, etc.

I recommend putting the click on another element instead. Having said that, you could try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('#helppage').fadeToggle('medium', function() {
      // code here
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, any suggestions on good tutorials to read on jquery and javascript syntax?

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there. http://learn.jquery.com/ is part of jquery itself and is pretty good.  A quick google search should find you some good resources. Stay away from W3Schools.com though!  :-)

Comment: how do i change this to only focus on the button rather than the whole document. Shouldn't it be this.document

Comment: i tried this as well this.document doesnt do anything this just does anywhere you click

Comment: if you have a button with an id of showHelp then you would do `$('#showHelp').on('click', function(){  $('#helppage').fadeToggle('medium'); });`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above, without changing your code:

```
function toggleHelp(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        if ($('#helppage').is(":visible"))  {
             $( "#helppage" ).fadeOut( "medium", function() {

             });
        } else {
             $( "#helppage" ).fadeIn( "medium", function() {

             });
        } 
    });
}
```